# I have an apparent major flaw in my CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with this css? It won't load in any browser. It was loading the other day, and I have no idea what I changed super recently to have destroyed it. And now apparently stack overflow wants me to add more details before i post and i dont know what else to do lol. EDIT: Now my Original problem is solved, but a new problem has arisen, Now theres extra space on height and width on my page, and it appears to be an HTML Problem now. EDIT: Now it looks like the problem lies within the CSS on all the .Text classes.

```
body {

    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/EpgMwgC.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 900px;

     }

/*http://i.imgur.com/p7f9wMQ.jpg*/


hr {

    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    left: 257px;
    bottom: -20px;
    display: block;
    border-color: #666;
}

div {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.ProvidenceTxt {

    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 490px;

}

.ReformedTxt {

    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: 756px;

}

.ChurchTxt {

    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    left: 550px;

}

.BoiseTxt {

    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    left: 758px;

}



#YoutubeImg {

position: relative;
width: 150px;
top: -110px;
left: 550px;


}

#FacebookImg {

position: relative;
width: 73px;
top: -134px;
left: 610px;

}

.YoutubeVidBoi {

    position: relative;
    left: 430px;
    top: -10px;

}

HTML:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="textstyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4">


        <head>
            <!-- The Title and Favicon of the Website -->
            <title>Providence</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="PRCfavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">


        </head>


        <body>

            <h1 class="ProvidenceTxt">Providence</h1>
            <h1 class="ReformedTxt">Reformed</h1>
            <h1 class="ChurchTxt">Church</h1>
            <h1 class="BoiseTxt">Boise</h1>

        <hr>

        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZAf3EhGuasVIxucTHB9V0A"><img id=YoutubeImg src="https://www.youtube.com/yt/brand/media/image/YouTube-logo-full_color.png" alt="Youtube Channel"> </a>


        <img id=FacebookImg src="https://img.clipartfest.com/c55c67101fd407bcce47c5ed59bf879e_facebook-announces-clickable-facebook-logo_530-300.png" alt="Facebook Page">


        </body>

        <br>

        <iframe class="YoutubeVidBoi" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bMdIX1mH6r8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <footer>


        </footer>


        </html>
```

Comment: For example you can post your html to know how the css is being applied.

Comment: missing a semi colon after border-color in your hr style. Because it is cascading anything beyond this point will fail to style.

Comment: ok well that didnt fix a whole lot, my main problem is that there's a ton of extra space on bottom and left of the page. HTML Is now in OG question

Answer (score 0):

The only issues that I can see is that you're missing a couple semicolons:

- Missing semicolon after "width: 100%" in the div element selector.
- Missing a semicolon after "border-color: #666" in the hr element selector (I see that this one was already mentioned by @danjbh in a comment).

I can't see any other problems, so hopefully this will get it resolved :)

Comment: The semicolon fixed some of the height problem for some reason, but i still have extra space. The problem appears to be in the HTML, so i put that into the Original question

Comment: I have got it loading now btw lol, but several other problems sprung up when i had that fixed

Comment: I understand, it happens to me all the time :)

Comment: Ok well it looks like for some reason all the problems lie in "Position: Relative" Why is this?

Comment: I was looking at the image from your imgur link. Is that a mockup for how you want the text to appear on the screen (above the YouTube video)?

Comment: ya, i actually just got it working this morning. Frikkin the position of everything being relative was bad apparently

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. Thanks for all the help everyone who commented, definitely made me aware of stupid missed colens and formalities lol, but it ended up being that I just had to switch literally everything to an absolute postion because for some reason everything having relative positions was screwing with the page width lol.